# save multiple matrices in dir after truncating

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am working with this code, based on some previous user examples. I am trying to read ascii files in the directory specified and only read the first 80 rows of data from each file (1020 total rows and 2 columns, originally).
This routine does not give me errors but it's unclear to me how the data is stored in MATLAB, and how I can then manipulate each of the new matrices of 80 rows I've just created. Can I give each .asc file that is now truncated a new file name or matrix assignment? I will next need to do a peakfinding algorithm on those 80 rows in each file, so I need each of them to be stored separately. Thanks!

```
folder = fullfile('Users', ...'Documents', 'MATLAB'); 

f = dir(fullfile(folder, '*.asc'));

    matrices = struct();

      for ii = 1 : numel(f)

          name = fullfile(folder, f(ii).name);
          O = dlmread(name);
         matrices.(f(ii).name) = O(1:80,:);
      end
```

Comment: Maybe do `matrices{ii}=O(1:80,:)`.

Comment: then you also have to delete the line matrices = struct()

Answer (score 0):

this won't work.

the loop loops all files in the directory. each file is read to a temporary matrix O, from which only the first 80 lines are stored into the structure matrices. 
BUT: the matrices structure will be referenced with the full file names of the corresponding asc files i.e. blabla.asc

Matlab structs are referenced by dots and consequently it forbids dots in field names for structs.

change you code to:

```
f = dir(fullfile(folder, '*.asc'));
matrices = struct();
for ii = 1 : numel(f)
    name = fullfile(folder, f(ii).name);
    O = dlmread(name);
    prf_sff = strsplit(f(ii).name, '.')
    matrices.(prf_sff{1}) = O(1:80,:);
end
```

then you can reference the matrix containing the first 80 lines of blabla.asc with:

```
matrices.blabla
```

Comment: Thanks, @johannes_lalala. I'm not clear on your advice. I input what you suggested (without the matrices.mynamehere line) and got:   refname = strsplit(f(ii).name, '.')[1]        
Error: Unbalanced or unexpected parenthesis or bracket.  However, David's suggestion of matrices{ii}=O(1:80,:)  does work and I get no error when I compile that. I'm unclear as to whether simply replacing David's suggestion of this matrices line and not changing anything else except deleting matrices = struct() will store each ascii file's first 80 rows separately or if it will override them. Thanks!

Comment: ah yes. I updated my answer.

Both David's and the original solution will save all the matrices in one "container" called matrices. Nothing will be overwritten. A cell array in the David's solution, a struct in the other.

The difference is how you access the matrices. In David's solution you access the matrices with matrices{x} where x is a number. You have to be cautious with the order of the files then! In your original solution you access the matrices by their file name. I altered it to the prefix of the file name (without the .asc). I.e. like this: matrices.fileprefix